# R: where can I find a list of all roclets available in roxygen2?

Tags: r, roxygen2, roxygen

A while ago the `roxygen2` documentation (R package to ease writing the documentation of R packages) contained a full list of the roclets available.

In the new version I installed on my laptop I can't manage to find it.
Is it still available somewhere? In alternative is there any way to get it from within R?

Comment: I'd recommend reading the man and NAMESPACE chapters at http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz

Comment: Thanks @hadley actually I did read them, I was just trying to find a comprehensive list explaining also the less used ones. If memory doesn't betray me (which is entirely possible) I remember before in the roxygen documentation the was a long list, with many more roclets than the one explained in your R packages book. Am I right?

Comment: There are only three roclets: collate, rd and namespace. Do you mean the roxygen tags?

Comment: mmm, then I have not understood what a roclet is.. I thought it was the name of the tags in roxyges.. and yes I meant the tags then.

Comment: Then no, there's no more comprehensive list than in the man chapter

Comment: thanks @hadley. And to find an explanation of roclets where should I look at? I searched for "roclet" in man and description but the word doesn't appear in the pages.

Comment: There's not much, apart from the source